# simplexml_load_file from file not ending with .xml

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to parse an xml file by starting with simplexml_load_file to load the contents.  The file comes from a wordpress using an xml feed generated by a .php file.

The problem is it never can load the xml file..I'm not sure what I can do to make this work.  Here is the code

```
 <?php

  $url = "http://marshallmashup.usc.edu/feed.php";

 $ch = curl_init();
  $timeout = 5; 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
 $result = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

  $rss = simplexml_load_string($result);

  if( ! $rss = simplexml_load_file($url,NULL, LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING) )
 {
   echo 'unable to load XML file';
 }
 else
  {
   echo 'XML file loaded successfully';
  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all after this line:

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

you should add this one:

```
$result = utf8_encode($result);
```

Said that, you'll have no problems with the function `simplexml_load_string($result);` which will correctly create a DOM based on the string you give to the function and that is the feed gotten from the php page. You can see the result using `var_dump($rss);` after the statement `$rss = simplexml_load_string($result);`.